# What is domain of convergence for the Laurent series of $\sqrt{1-z} + e^\frac{1}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I already compute the Laurent series, which is pretty easy using the Taylor series of both. Then I Know that we can define a branch cut for the square root function in $[1,\infty)$. And we can say that the $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ converges for $|z| > 0$. Then I have that in that branch cut the radius of convergence is $R = 1$ and I can say that it converges uniformly in $Ann(0,0,1)$. However, they ask me to discuss convergence at $|z| =1$ and I'm having problems with that. This series I know that at $(1,0)$ it can not converge since it's in the branch, but in the rest of the circle? and what can I say for $|z| > 1$?

Comment: If you mean the Laurent series centered at $0$ then please say so.

Comment: @zhw. Although a Taylor series is technically a Laurent series, it would be strange to talk about it that way. So I'd say it's pretty obvious that is what is meant.

Comment: I am not at all sure that the series couldn't possibly converge at the end point of the branch cut. So you'll have to consider the possibility that the series might converge at $z=1$ as well. For the convergence questions, you can throw away the $e^{1/z}$ part, since its series converges. For the rest, did you try estimating the size of the coefficients using Stirling's formula? It might give you what you need.

Comment: And for $|z|>1$, the series diverges. This is standard complex variables theory, since otherwise, your function would be analytic at $z=1$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen A Laurent series is not a Taylor series though.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Just to take an example, what about the Laurent series of this function in the annulus $\{1/2 < |z+1/2|<3/2\}?$

Comment: To make my previous comment more clear, consider the Taylor series of $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2},&x\ne0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$centered at $0$ and compare this to the Laurent series at $0$.

Comment: And the answer is ?????? lol

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen good idea about Stirling's formula, with that approximation I will be able to compute the ratio test to say if it converges or diverges at z = 1. Thank you.

Comment: @zhw. Oh, you're right. I should stop commenting late in the day after my brain has turned to jelly.

Comment: @zhw. I didn't get your comment. The square root have or not a Laurent for |z| < 1?

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with that. Laurent expansions can be centered at lots of points. If you intended it to be centered at $0,$ you should say so. That's all.